# AI problem (Colliding on itself even though it shouldn't)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm basically trying to make very basic AI where it uses random directions to move. It will some reason move inside of itself even though I created If statements that prevents this. It will only happen with the x coordinates and if I change the order it happens to the y coordinates. In this code, I have changed the order and it shows.

I Cannot see the problem and need help fast.
An example of what happens(list printed to see):

Player 1 Wins(Blue)

> [[205, 300], [210, 300], [215, 300], [220, 300], [225, 300], [225, 305], [225, 310], [225, 315], [225, 320], [225, 325], [225, 320]]

```
dir_x = -5
dir_y = 0
dir_x2 = 5
dir_y2 = 0

x = 600
y = 300
x2 = 200
y2 = 300


cool = True
list1 = []
list2 = []

player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0

speedP1,speedPN1 = 5,-5
speedP2, speedPN2 = 5, -5

while cool == True: 

        screen.fill(black)
        possible_cor = ([5,0],[-5,0],[0,5],[0,-5])
        choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
        if len(list2) != 0:
            if len(list2)%5 == 0:  
                if dir_y2 == 5:
                    possible_cor = ([5,0],[-5,0],[0,5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]

                if dir_y2 == -5:

                    possible_cor = ([5,0],[-5,0],[0,-5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]
                if dir_x2 == 5:

                    possible_cor = ([5,0],[0,5],[0,-5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]

                if dir_x2 == -5:

                    possible_cor = ([-5,0],[0,5],[0,-5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor) 
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]






        x += dir_x
        y += dir_y

        x2 += dir_x2
        y2 += dir_y2

        message_display(str(score1),20,1.9,12,text_objects2)
        message_display(str(score2),20,2.1,12,text_objects2)
        message_display((":"),20,2,12,text_objects2)

        lightbike(blue,x,y)
        lightbike(green,x2,y2)


        if speedP1 == 5 or speedPN1 == -5:
            list1.append([x,y])
        if speedP2 == 5 or speedPN2 == -5:
            list2.append([x2,y2])




        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print (event)
            #Exit 
            if event.type ==  QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if (event.type == KEYDOWN):

                #Player1

                if (event.key == 276): #LEFT
                    if dir_x == 0:
                        dir_x = speedPN1
                    if dir_y != 0:
                        dir_y = 0
                if (event.key == 275): #RIGHT
                    if dir_x == 0:
                        dir_x = speedP1
                    if dir_y != 0:
                        dir_y = 0
                if (event.key == 273): #UP
                    if dir_y == 0:
                        dir_y  = speedPN1
                    if dir_x != 0:
                        dir_x = 0
                if (event.key == 274): #DOWN
                    if dir_y == 0:
                        dir_y = speedP1
                    if dir_x != 0:
                        dir_x = 0

        #Boundaries
        if x + 2 > w or x - 2 < 0 or y + 2 > h or y - 2 < 0:
            print ("Player 2 Wins(Green)")
            return AI_GAME(total_score,score2+1,score1)
        if y2 + 2 > h or y2 - 2 < 0 or x2 + 2 > w or x2 - 2 < 0:
            print ("Player 1 Wins(Blue)")
            return AI_GAME(total_score,score2,score1+1)

        for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
            lightbike(blue,i[0],i[1])
            lightbike(green,j[0],j[1])
            if list1.count(i) > 1:
                print ("Player 2 Wins(Green)") 
                return AI_GAME(total_score,score2+1,score1)
            if list2.count(i) > 0:
                player2_score += 1
                if player1_score != 0:
                    print ("Player 2 Wins(Green)") 
                    return AI_GAME(total_score,score2+1,score1)
            if list1.count(j) > 0:
                player1_score += 1
                if player2_score != 0:
                    print ("Player 1 Wins(Blue)")
                    return AI_GAME(total_score,score2,score1+1)
            if list2.count(j) > 1:
                print ("Player 1 Wins(Blue)")
                print (list2)
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()







        if len(list1) > 500:
            del list1[0:1]
        if len(list2) > 500:
            del list2[0:1]



        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(30)

        if score1 ==3 or score2 == 3:
            cool = False
```

Comment: The code provided is the game full code

Comment: Really? I don't even see `import pygame`. And where is `AI_GAME` defined? Or `lightbike`... Or did you mean to say this is **not** the game's full code?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't completely understand what you are trying to do, I guess the part you are having problem with is:

```
                if dir_y2 == 5:
                    possible_cor = ([5,0],[-5,0],[0,5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]

                if dir_y2 == -5:

                    possible_cor = ([5,0],[-5,0],[0,-5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]
                if dir_x2 == 5:

                    possible_cor = ([5,0],[0,5],[0,-5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor)
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]

                if dir_x2 == -5:

                    possible_cor = ([-5,0],[0,5],[0,-5])
                    choices = random.choice(possible_cor) 
                    dir_x2 = choices[0]
                    dir_y2 = choices[1]
```

I see something you probably didn't take into account. Each if block changes the values of `dir_x2` and `dir_y2`. Therefore, the next if block will use those modified values to evaluate its condition. For example, if `dir_x2, dir_y2` is `0, 5` at the beginning, then the first if block may change it to `5, 0`. However, the condition of the third if block, `dir_x2 == 5`, is now satisfied, so it is also executed and may change `dir_x2, dir_y2` further to `0, -5`. I think this may not be what you want.

If this is the problem, the solution is to change the last three `if`s into `elif`s. Now every time this piece of code is run, at most one of the four blocks will be executed.